# R: Regression on a constant with autocorrelated errors

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to regress a series (`y`) on a constant with autocorrelation structure in errors modelled. I used `gls` function in the package `nlme` but R ran out of memory. I instead would like to use `arima()` function in the `stats` package with `xreg` option. Is it possible to do this when `y` is regressed only on a constant? How could I do this?

The code is:

```
r1 <- lm(d1 ~ 1)
auto.arima(residuals(r1))
```

After finding out orders of ARMA process for the residuals,
I did Generalised least squares from nlme package:

```
gls(d1 ~ 1, correlation=corARMA(p=2, q=2))
```

But R ran out of memory.
So I am wondering if I could run:

```
arima(d1, xreg=, order=c(2,0,2))
```

when the regression is of `d1` on a constant only.

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: I would have thought that the mean would have been an unbiased (and equal) estimate of the intercept in all cases, but based on some experimentation I'm wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `auto.arima` to do the whole model:

```
auto.arima(d1)
```

It will include a constant if it is required.

Comment: Just a question, I am trying to model autocorrelation in the errors before doing a regression of d1 on a constant.  Would auto.arima do it?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Errors from what? Before you do a regression, there are no errors.

Comment: r1 <_ lm(d1 ~ 1)  I regressed d1 on a constant before putting in ARMA structure and find out what ARMA structure fits the residuals from r1.  Then regress d1 on an constant with ARMA structure for the errors built in.

Comment: As I've already said, auto.arima does that for you. It will include a constant if required. That is identical to regressing on a constant with ARMA structure.

Comment: I get it now.  Thanks a lot.